# How to hide execution process of VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote below vba coding for automation purpose. But could you suggest me which steps can i remove to run more faster.

```
Sub listof()
    LQCC = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    ytqcl = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    tr = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    tqcp = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    ssel = Int(tr / tqcp)

    Dim ListofQCUsers() As Variant
    ReDim ListofQCUsers(LQCC) As Variant

    For y = 1 To UBound(ListofQCUsers)
        ListofQCUsers(y) = Range("f" & y + 1).Value
    Next y

    sampleselection = 0

    If ListofQCUsers(UBound(ListofQCUsers)) = Range("a2").Value Then
        Range("f2").Value = ListofQCUsers(UBound(ListofQCUsers))
        Range("f" & LQCC + 1).Value = ListofQCUsers(1)
        For y = 1 To UBound(ListofQCUsers)
            ListofQCUsers(y) = Range("f" & y + 1).Value
        Next y
    End If

    Range("f2", "f" & LQCC + 1).Delete

    For Z = ytqcl To 1 Step -1
        For x = 1 To UBound(ListofQCUsers)
            For d = 1 To ssel And Z <> 0
                If Z > 0 Then
                    If ListofQCUsers(x) <> Range("a" & Z).Offset(1, 0).Value Then
                        LSN = Sheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        Range("a" & Z).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 3).Copy
                        Sheets(3).Range("a" & LSN).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                        Sheets(3).Range("a" & LSN).Value = ListofQCUsers(x)
                        Range("a" & Z).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 3).Delete
                        sampleselection = sampleselection + 1
                    End If
                    Z = Z - 1
                End If
            Next d
            sampleselection = 1
            Z = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
            If x = 1 Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next x
        ytqcl = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    Next Z

    ytqcl = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("a2", "a" & ytqcl).Resize(1, 3).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

I want to assign processed claims for qc to different persons i.e., process person should not get the same claim for to do qc.

Above code giving 100% accurate data but i want to know where which steps are not required again and again.

Comment: Mast @ -some vba codes looks simple (less no. of lines) but it do all things, i want to know in above code which steps can replace with dynamic steps.

Comment: The first thing that you should do before you write another loine of code is download this free addin: [Smart Indenter](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/Indenter/).

Comment: Do you actual want to copy the formats over or just the values?

Comment: Check out the Code Review community they may be more likely to help you out. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You will get a significant speed boost by toggling `ScreenUpdating` and `Calculation`.

```
Sub listof()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Your Code

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Thomas Inzina @ what is the code for to increase cpu/system memory usage to run the macro?

Comment: There is not much that you can do to increase the CPU usage using the VBA,  But CPU usage isn't really your issue.  If you can provide me a download link, I'll look at it tomorrow night.  Using a Scripting Dictionary for a look up and arrays to hold the data would probably make this code run 50 times faster or more.